# Powershell Script to Kill all PIDs that are non-responsive for 3 minutes

Tags: powershell

I need some help with a powershell script to kill all PIDs that are non-responsive for 3 minutes.
This is my script, but is not doing the trick. This script is running, but i need it to run as in a while loop, forever since the computer is running till the end of the working time.

I need to have a list with all the processes that are unresponsive for a period of 3 minutes. After 3 minutes, if those processes from the list have the same status -eq NoT Responsing to kill them. I don't want to kill the processes that are not responsing for 5 seconds or so, only those that are hanging for more than 3 minutes.

My purpose is to kill the PIDs that are running with the status Not Responding for more than 3 minutes.

As you know, processes sometimes are unresponsive for a couple of seconds e.g IE hangs for 7 seconds till the server response with the DOM etc. hence I need to close all the pids that are hanging with the status Not Responsive for more than 3 min.

```
 while (1) {
    # if ( $allProcesses = get-process -name $pN -errorAction SilentlyContinue ) {



     foreach ($oneProcess in $allProcesses) {
         if ( -not $oneProcess.Responding ) {
                write "Status = Not Responding: Kill&  Restart.."    
                $oneProcess.kill()
                 ## restart ..
        } else {
               write "Status = either normal or not detectable (no Window-Handle)"
        }
     }

 start-sleep 5
 }
```

Comment: I need to have a list with all the processes that are unresponsive for a period of 3 minutes. After 3 minutes, if those processes from the list have the same status -eq NoT Responsing to kill them. I don't want to kill the processes that are not responsing for 5 seconds or so, only those that are hanging for more than 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution, not tested, is based on idea about storing the process info in a hashtable and performing a re-check after sleep period. Like so,

```
while($true){
    # Get a list of non-responding processes
    $ps = get-process | ?  { $_.responding -eq $false }
    $ht = @{}

    # Store process info in a hash table.
    foreach($p in $ps) {
        $o = new-object psobject -Property @{ "name"=$p.name; "status"=$p.responding; "time"=get-date; "pid"=$p.id }
        $ht.Add($o.pid, $o)
    }

    # sleep for a while
    start-sleep -minutes 3

    # Get a list of non-responding processes, again
    $ps = get-process | ?  { $_.responding -eq $false }

    foreach($p in $ps) {
        # Check if process already is in the hash table
        if($ht.ContainsKey($p.id)) {
            # Calculate time difference, in minutes for 
            # process' start time and current time
            # If start time's older than 3 minutes, kill it
            if( ((get-date)-$ht[$p.id].Time).TotalMinutes -ge 3 ) {
                # Actuall killing
                $p.kill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's certainly possible to store process objects in the hashtable, but in most cases all you need is process id. Mind that process ids are recycled. If you are spawning a lot of processes, it might be reasonable to check `$p.time` value so that newly created process isn't killed instead.

Comment: how to implement the $p.time check?  if($ht.ContainsKey($p.id)) -and ($p.time -ge 180) ?

Comment: @IonutCohen See the edit. Since the object within hashtable contains a DateTime, it's easy to do time math. Just subtract stored time from current time and see the difference in minutes.